# Packing Problem

Tags: analysis, packing-problem

Hey I'm trying to solve a problem of figuring out how many rectangles of a certain size would fit within a triangle and a trapezium, is there a formula that can be used for this?

Say I had a rectangle of size 1.6mx1m and a triangle of a length of 10m and a height of 4m, the trapezium is 8m long at the top and a height of 5m and 16m on the bottom, what would be the maximum amount of rectangles to fit in to two of the rectangles and two of the trapezium, no overhanging pieces.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. You might want to add some extra information and context. More people will be able (and willing) to help you that way.

Comment: Is the triangle isosceles, or right? If it's highly obtuse (which is possible, given what you've written) then you won't be able to fit any rectangles in it.

Comment: Yeah its iscoceles, the lower end is 10m and the height is 4m, so its made up 3 lengths of 10m+6.4m+6.4m